# A question about ring has 1 stable range

Tags: matrices, noncommutative-algebra, k-theory

I got this problem from my professor.It states that if $D$ is a division ring then ring of matrices $M_{n}(D)$ has 1 stable range.

A ring called has $1$ stable range if we get $Ra+Rb=1$ for some $a,b \in R$ then there is an element $t \in R$ such that $a+tb$ is invertible.

Comment: @Crostul I proved that  if $D$ is a division ring then$ D$ has $1$ stable range.

Comment: @Crostul I think the next step is how to prove that $M_{n}(R) $ has $1 $ stable range for any ring $R$ has $1$ in the stable range.